# How do I make error-prone ignore my generated source code?

Tags: java, android, gradle, errorprone

I've recently discovered [Error Prone](http://errorprone.info) and am integrating it into my Android build using the [Gradle plugin](https://github.com/tbroyer/gradle-errorprone-plugin) linked on their page.

Since our project is using Icepick (and some other code generating annotation processors), we have generated source code, which gets compiled in.  Unfortunately, some of the generated code triggers warnings in Error Prone, and I'd like to filter that noise out somehow.

The generated code shows up in the `app/build/generated/source/apt/debug` directory.  How can I exempt this code from Error Prone's steely gaze?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the flag `-XepDisableWarningsInGeneratedCode`

See this [issue](https://github.com/google/error-prone/issues/463) on GitHub

Answer (score 1):

In my case classes were annotated with `@AvroGenerated` and `-XepDisableWarningsInGeneratedCode` didn't work.

The solution was to exclude `build` directory from checks via `-XepExcludedPaths:.*/build/.*`

Answer (score 1):

Below a sample configuration tested while building gRPC protos, which is a scenario similar to the OPs with code generated into a target directory: `build/generated/*`

Generated protos are not marked with `@Generated`, so the aforementioned flag `-XepDisableWarningsInGeneratedCode` has no effect on the generated code and warnings are still issued.

Also the command line flag has to be prepended by `-XDcompilePolicy` as per Gradle output and by `-Xplugin:ErrorProne` as per the [documentation](http://errorprone.info/docs/flags).

**ErrorProne Gradle Plugin via command line args**

```
compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs << '-XDcompilePolicy=simple -Xplugin:ErrorProne -XepDisableWarningsInGeneratedCode'
}
```

The command line approach do not seem to have an effect with modern Gradle, but the next approach does.

**ErrorProne Gradle Plugin via options**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'net.ltgt.errorprone' version '3.1.0' // https://github.com/tbroyer/gradle-errorprone-plugin
}

dependencies {
    errorprone "com.google.errorprone:error_prone_core:2.20.0" // https://github.com/google/error-prone
}

compileJava {
    options.errorprone.disableWarningsInGeneratedCode = true   // for @Generated
    options.errorprone.excludedPaths = ".*/build/generated/.*" // for other generated scenarios, e.g. Protobuf
}
```

**Environment**

- ErrorProne Gradle Plugin: https://github.com/tbroyer/gradle-errorprone-plugin
- ErrorProne Core: https://github.com/google/error-prone
- OS Mac OS X 13.4.1 aarch64
- JVM 17.0.6 (Azul Systems, Inc. 17.0.6+10-LTS)
- Gradle 8.2