# Lombok and Google Errorprone not working together

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok, errorprone

I'm using `lombok-1.18.18` and google `error_prone_core-2.11.0` in my spring boot application.
When using `@EqualsAndHashCode` and `@NoArgsConstructor` from Lombok getting build error in Google Errorprone.
Error telling is telling something like below:

For  `@EqualsAndHashCode`:

```
error: [MissingBraces] The Google Java Style Guide requires braces to be u
sed with if, else, for, do and while statements, even when the body is empty or contains only a single statement.
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
```

For `@NoArgsConstructor` (there is constructor like  `public MyEntity(int someparam)`):

```
error: [UngroupedOverloads] Overloads should be grouped toge
ther, even when modifiers such as static or private differ between the methods; found ungrouped constructor overloads on line(s): 36
@NoArgsConstructor
^
    (see https://errorprone.info/bugpattern/UngroupedOverloads)
  Did you mean '@Setter'?
```

My Entity class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@ToString(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Table(name = "my_entity")
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {
```

Lombok Config:

```
lombok.copyableAnnotations += org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier
lombok.copyableAnnotations += org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy
lombok.copyableAnnotations += org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make error-prone ignore my generated source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39561334/how-do-i-make-error-prone-ignore-my-generated-source-code)

Comment: You likely also need a `lombok.config` file in your project with "lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true" in it.

Comment: @DavidConrad added `lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true` in lombok config but still getting error for lombok annotation like [MissingBraces]

Comment: And did you turn on the flag for Errorprone to tell it to disable warnings in generated code?

Comment: @DavidConrad I set in gradle config `options.errorprone { disableWarningsInGeneratedCode = true` ....}`

Comment: Sorry, it seems that flag only works for warnings, and for errors you must use `-XepExcludedPaths`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55335407/636009 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/55777408/636009